# Cyrillic labels of values displayed incorrectly

Tags: encoding, stata, cyrillic, windows-1251

I have a Russian language dataset in `.dta` format. Stata displays labels in a wrong way as a bunch of symbols. Seems that the issue is that when the file was created it was encoded as Windows-1251 and Stata uses different encoding to display it.

Please let me know if you have some ideas.

I tried to solve it running

```
clear all
set more off 
unicode encoding set Windows-1251
unicode translate file_name.dta
```

And obtain the following r(198) error:

(using Windows-1251 encoding)

> ```
> File summary (before starting):
>     1  file(s) specified
>     1  file(s) to be examined ...
>
> File file_name.dta (Stata dataset)
>   234 variable names okay, ASCII
>     1 variable name okay, already UTF-8
>   all data labels okay, ASCII
>     0 variable labels okay, ASCII
>   144 variable labels okay, already UTF-8
>    91 variable labels translated
>   r(198);
> ```

if I try:

```
unicode analyze file_name.dta
```

I also get an `r(3300)` error:

> ```
>  91 variable labels need translation
>         1 value-label name needs translation
>              st_vlload():  3300  argument out of range
>      examine_dta_vallab_content():     -  function returned error
>      examine_dta_vallabs_content():     -  function returned error
>       examine_dta_file():     -  function returned error
>           examine_file():     -  function returned error
>       do_examine_files():     -  function returned error
>             unicode_do():     -  function returned error
>        unicode_analyze():     -  function returned error
>                  <istmt>:     -  function returned error
>       r(3300);
> ```

Comment: https://www.stata.com/help.cgi?dta#strings says **Strings are encoded UTF-8 in Stata**… Related: [Stata Data File Format (.dta)](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000471.shtml)